Safely closing an input stream using Kotlin and Arrow
I'm working on an application that uses the arrow-kt library of Kotlin to execute some code as part of an AWS lambda. The function takes an InputStream as a parameter. It then needs to convert that stream into json data, execute some other functions using the parsed json, and return an arrow Either<Throwable, String> . It also needs to safely close the InputStream, regardless of any errors that may occur.
My initial thought was to use Closeable from the Kotlin std lib. Something like:
fun pipeline(inputStream: java.io.InputStream): Either<Throwable, String>
{
    return inputStream.use 
    { stream ->
        val input = IOUtils.toString(stream, Charset.defaultCharset())
        fromJson<S3EventNotification.S3Event>(input).fold({
            it.left()
        },{ event->
            val key = event.records.first().s3.s3object.key
            getZoomLocationData(key).fold({it.left()},{ it.toString().left})
        })
    }
}

The problem I ran into is that the use() function of Closeable masks any failures thrown within the block. Using this, there is no way to let the errors bubble up and be returned to the caller as an Either.
How can I call and close my InputStream in a safe way while still allowing errors to bubble up and be returned?

I'm not sure what you by saying use "masksfailures. It doesn't consume exceptions, exceptions are propagated to the caller. It doesn't interact withEither` as well, it should be pretty much transparent. What is the exact behavior you observe and what is your expected behavior? Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

@broot The code I provided doesn't even compile. I need to return a Either<Throwable, String> . Closeable.use returns Either<Serializeable, String> when passed an input stream.

Ok, but this has nothing to do with use. use doesn't interact in any way with Either. Apparently, you return Either<Serializeable, String> from your fold. Didn't you maen to do: fold({ it }, ...)?

Actually not, it.left() looks good. It's hard for me to reproduce as I would need all libraries. But it doesn't seem possible use has anything to do with your problem.

You were actually on the right track. In simplifying the example code, I accidently left out a key part. I updated it to show the relevant code now. I was calling 'it.left()' from inside the 'success' block. I don't know why that changed the return type, but once I fixed that, the code compiles.

Here is an example how it could be implemented using the Arrow Raise DSL:
fun pipeline(inputStream: java.io.InputStream): Either<Throwable, String> =
   either {
    val input = catch({
      inputStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText) 
    }) { raise(it)}

    val s3Event = fromJson<S3Event>(input).bind()

    getZoomLocationData(s3Event.records.first().s3.object.key).bind()
  }

The stdlib function use will take care of safely closing the stream after consumption.
Using bind() allows to remove the nested fold.
